# Extract YEAR from date to reference specific Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Current formula on sheet "A".

```
=ArrayFormula(sumproduct(('2023'!$J$17:J="W")*('2023'!K17:K="")*NOT('2023'!$L$17:$L="S")*('2023'!$F$17:F)))
```

I have a sheet named "2023". I want to look up the '2023' in the above formula based on the contents of cell A191 on sheet "A".

The issue is INDIRECT() leads to this:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumproduct((INDIRECT(RIGHT(a191,4))&"!$J$17:J="W"")*('2023'!K17:K="")*NOT('2023'!$L$17:$L="S")*('2023'!$F$17:F)))
```

The obvious problem is the quotation marks after J="W". How can I use indirect to pull the four digit year from cell A191 with the above statements?

I tried single quotes, CHAR(34), double quotes, etc., and I can't seem to make this work. I have searched but have not found an answer to this question.

I have created an example spreadsheet here docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/… On sheet "Backlog", go to cell D232. I want that cell to get the year date from cell A232 for the sheet name.

`=if(today()>=A232,ArrayFormula(sumproduct(('2023'!$J$17:$J="W")*('2023'!$K$17:$K<$A232)*NOT('2023'!$L$17:$L="S")('2023'!$F$17:$F))),"")`

'2023' should be extracted from the date.

Indirect and nested quotation marks, but the quotation marks keep causing a problem.

Comment: Your link: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/… does not work. Can you please fix this link.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try with:*

```js
=arrayformula(indirect(right(A17,4)&"!$J$17:J")="W")
```

[image]

Comment: Neither of those work for me.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.